# Add a rich text field in a wordpress plugin settings

Tags: wordpress, plugins, richtextbox

I'm working on a simple wordpress plugin that adds a functionality to some of the pages. I need a titel (which I've made with a simple input field) and then a body text(custom message), where I want to use rich text. Is it possible to add a Rich Text Field to my settings page for my plugin?

Thanks, Kasper

[Screen shot of the settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3uN5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [wp_editor() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_editor/). Simple example is:

```
wp_editor( array(), 'custom_message', array(
    'textarea_rows' => 9
) );
```

Here you create rich text field with empty content ( array() ), id=custom_message, and set property to make it 9 rows high.

Add this in your code where you create simple input "Custom title".